# Creating Rectangles one under each other

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I have a program that creates a specific number of rectangles according to how many I want. When I create 1 Rectangle the Height is 400 when I create 2 Rectangles then the height is 200 when I create 4 Rectangles the height is 100, I think you understand what I'm doing. Now I want to place them one under each other. I give you 3 examples.

[This is how it looks like when I create 1 Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdkJi.png)

And when I want to create 2 Rectangles the height should get divided by 2. I already did that and that's working but I can't place them
[like this under each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUxQx.png)

Only one more example if someone doesn't understand what I'm trying. This is how it should look [like when I create 5 Rectangles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9beob.png)

I tried putting them under each other like that:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(MyRectangle[i], Width / 2.0 - MyRectangle[i].Width / 2.0);
Canvas.SetTop(MyRectangle[i], i * 120);
```

But that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC42E.png), it's not on top of the screen, and the other problem is that when I would want to create 2 it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvi80.png). So I tried around with using i from the loop but I can't figure anything out. This is my code:

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255)));
        int howmanyrect = 3;
        Rectangle[] MyRectangle = new Rectangle[howmanyrect];

        if (howmanyrect == 1)
        {
            Rectangle OneRectangle = new Rectangle();

            OneRectangle.Fill = brush;
            OneRectangle.StrokeThickness = 2;
            OneRectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            OneRectangle.Width = 400;
            OneRectangle.Height = 400;

            Canvas.SetLeft(OneRectangle, Width / 2.0 - OneRectangle.Width / 2.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(OneRectangle, 30);

            myCanvas.Children.Add(OneRectangle);
            Content = myCanvas;
        }

       for (int i = 1; i <= howmanyrect - 1; i++)
        {
            MyRectangle[i] = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = brush,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 400,
                Height = 400 / howmanyrect
            };
            
            Canvas.SetLeft(MyRectangle[i], Width / 2.0 - MyRectangle[i].Width / 2.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(MyRectangle[i], i * 120);

            myCanvas.Children.Add(MyRectangle[i]);
            Content = myCanvas;
        }
```

Comment: It is probably time for you to take a look at other Panels than Canvas. In order to stack child elements vertically or horizontally you would use a StackPanel or (again) a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to fix your code :

```
      Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255)));
        int howmanyrect = 3;
        Rectangle[] MyRectangle = new Rectangle[howmanyrect];

        for (int i = 0; i < howmanyrect; i++)
        {
            var rectangle = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = brush,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 400,
                Height = 400 / howmanyrect
            };
            MyRectangle[i] = rectangle;
        
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, Width / 2.0 - rectangle.Width / 2.0);
            var distance = 10;
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 30 + i * (400 / howmanyrect) + distance );
            myCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
        Content = myCanvas;
```

Comment: @preqs Try modify the value of distance.

Comment: I did just by doing - 10 after Height = 400 / howmanyrect